# How to hide a button in Knockout.js based on bound value

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I have the following button in my HTML template that I only want to show if `CanCancel` is true:

```
<button data-bind="click: CancelProject, visible: CanCancel">Cancel Project</button>
```

The problem is the model takes 1-2 seconds to bind, so I actually see the button for a few seconds, then it disappears when the data is fully bound.  I want the button to be hidden, and then *appear* if `CanCancel` is true.

I've tried to use CSS to set the initial state of the button:

```
<button class="hidden" data-bind="click: CancelProject, visible: CanCancel">Cancel Project</button>
```

And in my CSS:

```
DIV.buttons button.hidden { display: none; }
```

However, when I do that, I never see the button.  This is because Knockout.js will not override the inline style of the button with `display: inherit;` if the value is true.

Is there a way to get Knockout to explicitly set the inline display style no matter what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty solution to this is as follows:

```
<button class="hidden" data-bind="click: CancelProject, style: { display: CanCancel ? 'inherit' : ''}">Cancel Project</button>
```

See more about the style binding [here.](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html)

All that said, it's quick and dirty, and you might want to go with Matt's answer if you're working with a larger project/framework.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I've found a few easy ways to fix this.  Probably the easiest is by using the [style binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html):

```
<button class="hidden" data-bind="click: CancelProject, style: { display: CanCancel ? 'inherit' : 'none' } ">Cancel Project</button>
```

The `hidden` CSS selector will set the initial state to hidden, and the bound inline style will override this when the model is bound.

The second way might be a little bit more flexible.  I added a CSS class to the `<body>` tag:

```
<body class="loading">
```

Now, I can hide certain elements while the page is loading:

```
BODY.loading DIV.buttons { display: none; }
```

Lastly, when I bind the data, I can remove the class:

```
ko.applyBindings(model);
$(document.body).removeClass('loading');
```

This would allow me to control exactly how various elements behave when the page is being loaded using pure CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I usually wrap everything that's going to be bound by knockout in a div set with `display:none` and then either make it visible with (for example) jQuery right after the `ko.applyBindings`, or else use a custom knockout binding to make it visible linked to a `loaded`, `ready` or similar property (useful if your VM involves loading data via AJAX) or even just a `with` binding in my view model.

Here's a simple custom binding that uses jQuery's `.show()` to make an element visible, even if it was initially set to `display:none`:

```
ko.bindingHandlers["realVisible"] = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var val = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (val) {
            $(element).show();
        }
        else {
            $(element).hide();
        }
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var val = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (val) {
            $(element).show();
        }
        else {
            $(element).hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uChDj/)

Comment: Oh so like hide the entire UI until everything is databound?  That's probably not a bad idea..